# How to make my python code more easy to track object attributes?

Tags: python, fortran, readability

I have been reading some fortran project source code. Fortran subroutines can accept both 'in' and 'out' variables, which make it possible to specify what variables change in the subroutine. For example,

```
subroutine Foo(A, B, C)
    real*8; intent(in)::A
    real*8; intent(out)::B
    real*8; intent(out)::C
```

When I `call Foo(A ,B ,C)`, I would know that `A`, `B`, `C` may change in the subroutine.

However, I usually write python code in this way:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    def method_a(self):
        self.a = (self.a)**2
    def method_b(self):
        self.b = (self.b)**2
```

While in my main program

```
foo=Foo()
foo.method_a()
foo.method_b()
print(foo.a)
```

If I am not familiar with this code, it is extremely difficult to track what happens to `foo.a`, because I don't know if any method changes `foo.a`.

So, how to make my python code more easy to track object attributes?

Edit: I have to clarify that I have much more python experience than fortran. My question is how to make source code more easy for readers to track object attributes.

Comment: Use descriptive method names,  extensive documentation and try to minimize the amount of surprise of your users. And if foo.a may change under too complex circumstances, use a pseudo private variable (prefix with _) and getters/property decorators.

Comment: really? any compulsory way to make such variable changes visible？

Comment: Python descriptors let you run some code when an attribute is accessed. In the descriptor, you can add logging or anything else that helps you https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html.

Comment: That is not what I want, @AviahLaor . I want to make my code more readable, not to log every changes.

Comment: See the `property()` built-in.  That isn't exactly what you are asking, but you could use it to do close to what you are asking.  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#property.  Also remember that it doesn't make sense to try to write Fortran in Python, write Python in Python.

Comment: You are using at least 3 different terms, all with a different meaning, to describe what you are after ("track object attributes", "make change visible", "make your code more readable"). If you are looking for ``const`` qualifiers, explicit references, etc. you are doomed: they don't exist in Python. Don't try to map patterns/idioms from language A that don't apply to language B. Python has extensive support for all OO features you want to show/hide complexity (plus many others). Design an API that is easy to use, document it and call it a day. My 2 cents.

Comment: @cdarke  "The determined Real Programmer can write Fortran programs in any language."

Comment: @VladimirF: I resisted that quote, which was meant as a criticism of "Real Programmers".  But I think it makes the same point.